# Finding all indices of elements satisfying a certain condition in a large matrix gives MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My environment is Python 3.6 64bit with 64bit win 10 16GB ram.

I have a ndarray with shape (260923,). I want to find index of all elements that's greater than a threshold. I am using this code but it gives a Memory error. And in the task manager, I can see all my ram used up.

```
x_selected = x[:,x_attr]
index_right = (x_selected >thres).nonzero()[0]
```

I have 16GB of ram and changed my PyCharm heap memory to 6GB and the problem persists. 
This is how the ndarray looks like in debugger. 
[image]

This is the complete error:
[image]

what should I do to get all the index?

Clarification:

x is another ndarray with shape (260923,225). x_attr is just an integer. So "`x_selected = x[:,x_attr]`" is just selecting a column from x (2d array). This is how x looks like in debugger: 
[image]
The MemoreyError happens when I try to find the index (the codes I wrote above)
And if I shrink the rows of x_selected, the code works.

```
#This does NOT work
index_left = (x_selected <= thres).nonzero()[0]
#This works however
index_left = (x_selected[0:1000] <= thres).nonzero()[0]
#This does NOT work Error: "Comparing a sparse matrix with a scalar "
#error:  " raise NotImplementedError(" >= and <= don't work with 0.")"
test = list(x[:,x_attr])
if test[1]<=thres:
    a=1
```

Comment: Also, I have tried np.where(). It also generates a MemoryError

Comment: Did you try to run your code without pycharm?

Comment: @JulioDanielReyes I just tested on the console. Same MemoryError. I am downloading Anaconda distribution and see if any luck

Comment: There is not enough info here to reproduce this. What is `x` (type and size) what is `x_attr` (type and size)? Is it `x_selected = x[:,x_attr]` where the MemoryError happens? (looks like from IDE but not 100% clear).

Comment: @AndyHayden Thank you. Clarification on the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WFM on an x32 machine with 1,25GB of RAM. So the issue must be something not related to the specific code you presented.

Doing the operation one step at a time and checking memory consumption by variables, by the process and objects' internal state might give you a clue.

(As is the good old problem localization: if it goes away when you throw away other parts of the code, or throw everything away then start adding it back. Adding/removing half the amount at a time will give you a result in a logarithmic number of steps.)

```
In [41]: x=np.random.randint(2**30,size=(260923*225),dtype=np.int64).reshape(
    ...: (260923,225))

In [42]: x.nbytes
Out[42]: 469661400

In [43]: x_selected = x[:,0]

In [44]: x_selected.nbytes
Out[44]: 2087384

In [45]: from dump import dump

In [46]: dump(x_selected)
T : [ 728497578 1063110548   71820681 ...,  701362408 1030850648  908176708]
base : [728497578 297238747 162734746 ..., 262530510 654517286 329271071]
ctypes : <numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x028DEC10>
dtype : int64
flags :   C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
flat : <numpy.flatiter object at 0x027A3C30>
imag : [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
itemsize : 8
nbytes : 2087384
ndim : 1
real : [ 728497578 1063110548   71820681 ...,  701362408 1030850648  908176708]
shape : (260923,)
size : 260923
strides : (1800,)

In [58]: x.base is None
Out[58]: False    #due to .reshape(), x does not own its memory

In [57]: x_selected.base is x.base
Out[57]: True      # but they use the same memory anyway, so x_selected does not use up extra

In [48]: c=(x_selected >1000000)

In [49]: c.nbytes
Out[49]: 260923     #c is an ndarray of bools, each bool is thus 1 byte

In [50]: n=c.nonzero()

In [59]: sys.getsizeof(n)
Out[59]: 32     #just holds a reference to the sole element

In [51]: r=n[0]

In [52]: r.nbytes
Out[52]: 1042656
```

Comment: Thank you. With your help, it seems I debugged the problem now. Thank you ! The problem looks like in the variable "thres" which somehow turns to a sparse matrix itself.